# Node sass not compiling locally

Tags: css, command-line, sass, compass-sass, npm-scripts

newbie here learning how to use sass by building a dummy project. I am using command line to compile my main.scss file (which contains many imports from partials) into style.css file.

> npm run compile:sass

Whenever I make changes in my sass files, the changes do not occur in CSS unless unless i save different files many times.

Even though i used watch script in my package.json (code attached and screenshot of the command file) file, and I followed 3 different tutorials on npm init, I believe there seems to be no mistake there.

I have tried restarting my windows again and again, I even restarted my command line. Also restarted my command line without the watch command. The only solution I could find is that i save different partials some 5 6 times which is somehow taking too much time. It took me 30 minutes to have that transition: all 0.2s line to process into the stylesheet.

I have a 512 gb ssd and 16 gb ram so computer speed does not seem to be an issue.

In the attached picture, picture 1 has everything saved but the transition property is not converted, in picture 2 you will find transition property is converted completely randomly after saving many times. After that you will find command line showing that sass code is compiling without any problem.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHsSf.png

```
    {  "name": "projectnatours",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "trying from scratch",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w"  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss -wo css/"
```

or:

```
"compile:sass": "node-sass  -rw sass -o css"
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response, however the problem still remains the same (I could not apply the second script, I am new to coding, I am still googling, I only applied the first one)